# Multiple Completion emails sent to In-person Host via DocuSign API

Tags: c#, docusignapi

The Number of emails received is equal to the number of in-person signers added to the envelope

I am trying to reduce the number of emails received to the In-person host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the host is hosting multiple signers, they get an email for each one, just as any other recipients that may be added more than once to an envelope.
There's no way to suppress multiple emails to the same recipient if that recipient is appearing more than once in the transaction.